# Android i can see my device ID in Developer Options, but not in my coding

Tags: android

[image]

```
final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
        tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
        tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();

TextView lblVersion= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtDeviceID);
        lblVersion.setText("Device ID : "+tmDevice);
```

i get device ID is null, why?

Comment: Please refer to the TelephonyManager documentation. `getDeviceId()` returns the IMEI or ESN, *not* the development device id. If it returns null, you probably don't have Telephony in your device. You're looking for something along the lines of `Secure.ANROID_ID`.

Comment: @323go But the result are different with the screen i have posted? when i use ANDROID_ID ?

Comment: He's not suggesting that `ANDROID_ID` is the value, he's suggesting that you use `ANDROID_ID` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things which people call a "device ID". Development device ID is different from what you get from `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()` (and also different from `Secure.ANDROID_ID`). This [Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/4PcMd_E5yV4) seems to have done some research and narrowed it down to this [code and related comment](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#L2658):

> Returns the device identity that verifiers can use to associate their scheme to a particular device. This should not be used by anything other than a package verifier.

In short, don't try to use the Development Device ID. [Use a different ID instead](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html).

Comment: Sorry,i just want the Development ID or Product SN

Comment: The development ID and Product S/N are two different things. There's no universal way to get the Product S/N. You might be lucky and find it in extended settings, but most of the time, they're pretty tight-lipped about where it is. ANDROID_ID, as pointed out in my initial comment, is your best bet.